# "if !x" working - "if !x or !y" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to exclude in a jquery script two containers from unchecking the checkboxes inside them, so I made an if:

```
$('#newform li :checkbox').change(function() {
    var exclude = $(this).closest('div');
    if (!exclude.hasClass('size') || !exclude.hasClass('price'))
        $(this).closest('ul').find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

It's not "excluding" nothing right now, but if I remove the `||` from the if it will work for that only class. Where is the problem?

Comment: "!(a || b)" is "!a && !b"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
if ($('#your_element').is('.size, .price')) {
    $(this).closest('ul').find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
}
```

This checks against multiple classes.

Comment: Thanks it's working with `is()`. I'll accept in 7 minutes :)

Comment: @ChazyChaz, feel free to up vote and accept the answer. Thanks!